# A problem about indefinite integral in measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

tirple$(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$

Suppose $\xi$ is a random variable.Indefinite integral$$\varphi(B)=\int_B\xi\mathbb{d}P \quad\forall B\in\mathcal{A}$$

I saw in a textbook:

> If $E(\xi)$ exists(**not necessary finite**),then $\varphi $ is $\sigma$-finite.

Obviously,if $E(\xi)$ is finite the statement is true.But I have no idea when $E(\xi)$ is infinite.

(We can assume $\xi\ge0$ a.e.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\Omega = \bigcup_n \xi^{-1}([0,n])$$

It is easy to see that each set in the union has finite $\phi$ measure (because $P$ is a finite (probability) measure).